# How to check if openvpn is connected in Upstart?

Tags: boot, mysql, upstart, openvpn, arm

I need to run a script after mysql and openvpn are started (Ubuntu for ARM).

I can succesfully run the script with upstart with this .conf:

```
# my upstart for logging boot

start on (starting openvpn and started mysql)

script
    cd /home/ubuntu/developedGZ/provaMySql/
    ./provaMySql
end script
```

The script always run after mysql but not after openvpn.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is `openvpn` an emmitting service there? I would rather it focussed on the network side of things by using upstart's `net-device-up` directive:

```
start on (started mysql and net-device-up IFACE=tun0)
```

You'll probably need to poke that around (I'm not sure what your VPN tunnel device is named (refer to `ifconfig -a`).